# Web App Publishing Issues: How does this work?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

Racking my brain on why doGet() changes but doPost() does not when I publish an update.

## doGet()

### code

```
var version="0.4.3" // fixed MimeType.

function doGet(req) {
  var respData = {
    'function': 'doGet',
    version: version,
    request: req,
    message: 'Getting...',
    timestamp: (new Date()).toISOString(),
  }
  debug && console.log(respData)
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(respData)+'</pre>')
}
```

### GETs

Output of version 0.4.1:
[image: Version 0.4.1]

Now I increment and save a new version (0.4.3 in this case):
[image: Version 0.4.3]
Note that it is immediately available to the web. The Stackdriver logging supports this.

## doPost()

### code

```
function doPost(post) {
  var log = {
    'function': 'doPost',
    success: true,
    timestamp: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    version: version,
    message: 'Posting...',
    request: post,
  }
  debug && console.log(log)

  // create response item
  const response = ContentService.createTextOutput()
  response.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)

  // check post parameters

  // echo postParams
  response.append(JSON.stringify(log))
  return response
}

function testDoPost(){
  const dev = '<dev-url>' // URL hidden
  const prod = '<prod-url>' // URL hidden
  const params = {
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(logEntryTemplate),
    //muteHttpExceptions: true,
  }

  Logger.log('testDoPost('+version+'): \nparams: '+ JSON.stringify(params))
  const resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(prod, params)    
  Logger.log('HTTP Status: '+resp.getResponseCode())
  Logger.log(resp.getContentText())

}
```

When I run `testDoPost()` I get proper Logger logs:
[image: Logger.log v0.4.3]
.. but the Stackdriver logs still show version 0.4.0 (which had an erroneous enum (`MimeType.JSON` vs. `ContentService.MimeType.JSON`)).
[image: Stackdriver log]
This is the same regardless of just saving the script or republishing.

## Publish New

Now when I publish a *new* version (0.5.0) vs. update web app, I can see the changes to `doPost()` immediately:
[image: Stackdriver log v0.5.0]

**Why the difference in behavior on Update and Publish New for `doGet()` vs. `doPost()` ?!?**

This is caused me about 2-days worth of headaches just to get to this point (which I thought I would be finished in 4 hours!)!!

Comment: What's your question? It isn't clear to me what your procedure is when you talk about "increment and save new version" and "publish new"

Comment: @tehhowch when you deploy a web up you have a choice to UPDATE an existing version or deploy a NEW version. The update works fine for `doGet()` but only the new version works for `doPost()`. Why?

Comment: You can't "update" a script version - once saved, a script version is immutable. Your webapp can be set to run either an existing version (that you saved from *File -> Manage Versions*) or from the *Publish -> Deploy as Web App* menu you can select "New" and use the current state of the script editor (i.e. **HEAD** if viewing your project in [Script Dashboard](https://script.google.com/home)  to create the script version that the webapp executes. Please be clear and meaningful in your question. If all else fails, please provide an explicit MCVE and repro instructions.

Comment: @tehhowch Note that does not seem to be the case with the doGet() function. Every save updates the script.

Comment: Are you sure you're testing the same url? the `/dev` url always returns your script functions as they have been *saved* to HEAD (saved != versioned). The `/exec` url only returns the most recently published version, regardless of the current HEAD.

Comment: @techowch Not using the /dev url at all. What is bothering me is the different behavior between doGet() and doPost(). I am using only /exec as I kept getting "The document has moved" notices from /dev. (1) any save changes the behavior of /exec when doing and HTTP GET. (2) an update on a current project version does not change HTTP POST behavior (but does HTTP GET). (3) ONLY a new project version deploy changes the behavior of HTTP POST.

Comment: Also note that there are some open bugs with similar issues (doPost()) deploys not working. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79311029 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62196692